# Argand's inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm trying to understand an operation that has been done in the process of prooving the following statement:

If $p$ is a complex poylnomial function thus that $p(z)= \sum_{k=0}^n c_k z^k, n \geq 1$, then we find that every disk $D$ around $a$ contains a $b$ in the interior of D so that $|p(b)|<|p(a)|$.

At the beginning they look at

$$\begin{aligned} p(a+w) &=\sum_{k=0}^{n} c_{k}(a+w)^{k} \\ &=\sum_{k=0}^{n} c_{k} \sum_{i=0}^{k}\left(\begin{array}{c}k \\ i\end{array}\right) a^{k-i} w^{i} =\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\sum_{k=i}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}k \\ i\end{array}\right) c_{k} a^{k-i}\right) w^{i} \\ &=p(a)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{k=i}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}k \\ i\end{array}\right) c_{k} a^{k-i}\right) w^{i}=p(a)+\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{i} w^{i} \end{aligned}$$

Now my question:

1. Why does this equality hold: $\sum_{k=0}^{n} c_{k} \sum_{i=0}^{k}\left(\begin{array}{c}k \\ i\end{array}\right) a^{k-i} w^{i} =\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\sum_{k=i}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}k \\ i\end{array}\right) c_{k} a^{k-i}\right) w^{i}$?

Comment: It is just two different ways to sum over all indices $i, k$ satisfying $0 \le i \le k \le n$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I := \{(k,i) \in \{0, \dots, n\}^2: i \leq k\}$. Then it is easy to verify that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n c_k \sum_{i=0}^k { k \choose i} a^{k-i} w^i = \sum_{(k,i) \in I} c_k { k \choose i} a^{k-i} w^i. $$
Using another parameterization for the set $I$ one obtains
$$ \sum_{(k,i) \in I} c_k { k \choose i} a^{k-i} \omega^i = \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{k=i}^n c_k { k \choose i} a^{k-i} \omega^i, $$
which is the formula on the right hand side in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer that solved my problem.